# Not able to get wget -np -nH to not download the parent directories

Tags: unix, wget

I have made 6 attempts to not download the parent directories and all have failed. Can someone advise on my flag errors.

**torify wget -r -N --no-parent -R "index.html*" -nH http://somewebsite/Dir_a/Dir_b/Dir_c/ -P /toMyLocation**

I have been successful only in removing the root directory but still get the parents /Dir_a/Dir_b/

When I only want the Dir_c and all files inside.

I am using unix, zshell, torify, wget.

what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get stubborn sometimes where I can't let go. Finally found my issue. I needed to  add the --cut-dirs=<#> where <#> is the number of top directories to omit. so the correct command ended up being:

**torify wget -r -N --no-parent -R "index.html*" -nH --cut-dirs=2 http://somewebsite/Dir_a/Dir_b/Dir_c/ -P /toMyLocation**